# How to install an older version of an UWP App over a newer version?

Tags: uwp

assumed that I installed one of my UWP Apps with the version number 1.0.0.5.
For some reasons I need to install the same App but with version 1.0.0.4.

If I run the *Add-AppDevPackage.ps1* install script I get an error saying that it is not possible to install the app because there is already a newer version installed.

Important to know the situation takes place on a remote machine.
The version numbers are generated by a build agent which means that a higher version number doesn't need to be the newer version.

It might be possible to change that but it would be much more easier if I just could overide an existing installed app.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the version number, you can backup the data, reinstall the app and restore the data. It will be essentially the same.

Data is stored in the path `AppData\Local\Packages\{AppFolder}`.

Comment: The problem is that the version number does not relate to the actuallity of the app. This happens because the version number will be generated from a build agent. So reinstall the app is not a solution because the app I want to install may contain changes which the already installed doesn't have.

Comment: @Portikus, "because the app I want to install may contain changes which the already installed doesn't have" , why you think re-install cannot have that changes? Are there any differences for the app between for re-install  and upgrade besides data and setting?

Comment: And how would you reinstall an app?